# RESHAPE failed to prepare when invoking tf.signal.stft in tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am building a flutter app that needs to record an audio and predict some label using a tflite model I built. For linking the audio recording and tflite I use the flutter plugin tf-lite audio (https://github.com/Caldarie/flutter_tflite_audio).

The tensorflow model works on colab but when I launch the app and inference happens hence when it calls interpreter.invoke(), the following error occurs:

```
TensorFlow Lite Error: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:58 stretch_dim != -1 (0 != -1)
TensorFlow Lite Error: Node number 26 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: Must call allocateTensors().
2
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file tflite_audio/SwiftTfliteAudioPlugin.swift, line 290
* thread #2, queue = 'conversionQueue', stop reason = Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    frame #0: 0x00000001a672ee08 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x1a672ee08 <+0>: ret
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_reportToDebugger:
    0x1a672ee0c <+0>: b      0x1a672ee08               ; _swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_shouldReportFatalErrorsToDebugger:
    0x1a672ee10 <+0>: adrp   x8, 341475
    0x1a672ee14 <+4>: ldrb   w0, [x8, #0x7c8]
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

This error message appears even though I added allocateTensors in the SwiftTfliteAudioPlugin.swift file here:

```
var interval: TimeInterval!
        var outputTensor: Tensor!
        
        do {
            // Copy the `[Int16]` buffer data as an array of Floats to the audio buffer input Tensor.
            let audioBufferData = Data(copyingBufferOf: buffer.map { Float($0) / maxInt16AsFloat32 })
            try interpreter.copy(audioBufferData, toInputAt: 0)
            
            // I added this line
            try interpreter.allocateTensors()
            
            // Calculate inference time
            let startDate = Date()
            try interpreter.invoke() //required!!! Do not touch
            interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate) * 1000
            
            // Get the output `Tensor` to process the inference results.
            outputTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
            print(outputTensor as Any)

        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

In the tflite model here is the [problematic node on netron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzu39.png)

It looks like it is only squeezing the first dimension so maybe it cannot because as you can see on the [summary of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzu39.png) the first dimension is None, I tried some tricks to avoid having this None but I am not familiar enough with tensorflow to be sure about the validity of the operations I am doing.

I have boiled down my model to the minimal size and this node is between these 2 lines of code, so I suspect the tf.signal.stft function to do this reshaping but have no idea.

```
spectrograms = tf.signal.stft(waveforms,
                                     frame_length=self.fft_size,
                                     frame_step=self.hop_size,
                                     pad_end=False)

magnitude_spectrograms = tf.abs(spectrograms)
```

Can anyone help on this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, you need to call `allocateTensors` first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I had already added this call when I first ran into the error. I edited my post to show it.